# I'm having [awk-formatting] problems

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request, clean-up

I'd suggest burning [awk-formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/awk-formatting):

- total questions 43
- no description or information
- 39 questions are also tagged as [awk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/awk)
- Oldest question Nov 2010, newest question Nov 2018

I would just tag the 4 questions as [awk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/awk) and eliminated the [awk-formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/awk-formatting) as it does not bring any extra value. The questions seem to address *sometimes* formatted related issues with respect to reading files and writing output. This, however, is the core-business of awk. The questions themselves do not look in particular different to any other [awk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/awk) question.

The tag itself seems to be the result of overcategorization and just creates noise. If the tag, for whatever reason, deserves to exist than we should also make [awk-math](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/awk-math) [awk-strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/awk-strings), [awk-fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/awk-fields), etc ...

Comment: I'd espouse a synonymization instead.

Comment: This doesn't need to be burned. If anything, we would make it a synonym of [[tag:awk]], as Makoto suggested. But, I advise caution because the mere fact that a tag isn't used very often and doesn't have a wiki is not sufficient grounds to remove it. Ideally, we need some of [the awk experts](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/awk/topusers) to weigh in on what they think is best. Does this tag help them to find questions to answer, or is it completely pointless?

Comment: Thanks for the input. I've been talking already with some of the higher powers and we've synonymized it for now. Thanks a lot for the input.